# JavaScriptコード内でThymeleafを使用したい

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring

HTML内に記載しているJavaScriptコード内でThymeleafを使用したいです。
ソースコードは以下の通りです。
具体的には、Thymeleafで"${i}"を指定している為、
"i" 変数の中身をvalueとして参照したいです。

```
<a href="javascript:document.f.page.th:value = "${i}";document.f.submit();">
```

どなたかアドバイスをお願いします。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/286184

Answer (score 0):

なんとなく、気持ちは察することができるのですが、状況を把握しきれないので、うまく答えられません。下記の辺りを確認してみてはどうでしょうか。

- このjavascriptは操作対象の`form`要素があるのではないでしょうか？ その中の`input`タグの書き方次第で、正解が変わってしまうかと思います。
- `:value`の`:`は`.`でしょうか？
- `"${i}"`は`'${i}'`ではないでしょうか？`"`だと、属性値が途中で途切れていまいます。